# Confusion in file functioning and append function using Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have two questions for an exam.

```
t2=("A","B","Hello")
alist=["Barney",["Wilma"]]
print(alist[1].append(t2))
```

answer:

```
None
```

I thought it would be `[“Wilma”,(“A”,”B”,”Hello”)]`

AND

file has:

```
James,8,9
Sonia,7,6
Clark,4,5
```

code:

```
endofprogram=False
try:
    infile=open("names.txt",”r”)
except IOError:
    print("Error reading file")
    endofprogram=True
if endofprogram==False:
    for line in infile:
        line.strip('\n')
        alist=line.split(',')
        print(alist)
```

Answer

```
['James','8','9\n']
['Sonia','7','6\n']
['Clark','4','5\n']
```

Why is '\n' still there?
LASTLY:

```
def change(aList):
    aList=aList.pop()
    aList.append(5)
    return
def main():
    mylist=[1,2,[3]]
    change(mylist)
    print(mylist)
main()
```

Answer:

```
[1,2]
```

Why is this the answer? shouldn't it be `[1,2,5]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `list.append` is an in-place operation, it modifies the list in-place and returns `None`.

```
>>> lst = []
>>> repr(lst.append(1)) #returns None
'None'
>>> lst                 #list modified
[1]
```

- Strings are immutable, you need to re-assign the result of `.strip()` call back to a variable.

```
line = line.strip('\n') #re-assign the new returned string to a variable.
alist = line.split(',')
```

- You re-assigned `aList` to a different list, so the `.append()` call won't affect the originally passed list.

```
def change(aList):
    aList = aList.pop() #Now aList points to [3] not to `[1, 2, [3]]`
    aList.append(5)
```

You can simply use the assignment statement here:

```
aList[-1] = 5
```

Comment: Hi. Could you elaborate a bit. I did not understand you! thanks

Comment: @Newbie I've added some more explanation and also go through basic [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Answer (score 1):

1. [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) is an operation which returns `None` because it modifies the list in place. You must print the actual list to get the output you expect.
2. `line.strip("\n")` does strip the newline, but it never gets saved anywhere. Strings are immutable in python, thus [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) returns a new string with the characters stripped. The correct way to use it is to say `line = line.strip("\n")`.

Example 1:

```
>>> alist[1].append(t2)
>>> print alist
['Barney', ['Wilma', ('A', 'B', 'Hello')]]
```

Example 2:

```
>>> line = "Foo\n"
>>> line.strip("\n")
'Foo'
>>> line
'Foo\n'
>>> line = line.strip("\n")
>>> line
'Foo'
```

Comment: Hi! I got your 2nd answer but for the first one how would I know when it is suppose to return something and when none?

Comment: You need to read the documentation. There isn't really a rule for that.

Answer (score 1):

The append function returns nothing, thus the None result. It only appends to the list.

The strip function only removes characters at the end & beginning. If you are working on Windows, the actual line ending may well be \n\r, making the last character \r. That is not removed by your strip command.

Your third problem is because in the change function, the aList value is lost as soon the function Change exists. You should do:

```
def Change(l):
  l.pop()
  l.append(5)
```

In Python, an assignment does not change any underlying variable. Instead, the name is bound to a new value. Thus, after the line `alIst = aList.pop()`, aList points to `[3]`, but is no longer linked the the myList object. After the append function, aList points to `[3, 5]`, but this object is garbage collected as soon as `Change` returns.